# Конверсия с csv в xml

Tags: c#, xml, csv

Здравствуйте. Реализовал конвертацию следующим образом:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

  XElement xmlf = new XElement("Folder",
      new XElement("name", "NASI PARTNERZY HANDLOWI"),
      from str in source
      let fields = str.Split(';')
      select
      new XElement("Placemark", new XElement("name", fields[0]),
          new XElement("description", fields[1]),
          new XElement("styleUrl", fields[2]),
          new XElement("ExtendedData",
              new XElement("Data",
                  new XAttribute("name", "opis"),
                  new XElement("value", fields[3])),
              new XElement("Data", new XAttribute("name", "Informacje:"),
                  new XElement("value", fields[4])),
              new XElement("Data", 
                  new XAttribute("name", "Telefon:"), 
                  new XElement("value", fields[5])),
              new XElement("Data", 
                  new XAttribute("name", "E-mail"), 
                  new XElement("value", fields[6])),
              new XElement("Data", 
                  new XAttribute("name", "Strona:"), 
                  new XElement("value", fields[7])),
              new XElement("Data", 
                  new XAttribute("name", "gx_media_links"), 
                  new XElement("value", fields[8]))),
          new XElement("Point", new XElement("coordinates", fields[9]))));
```

В конце получаю правильную структуру, но заполненую неправильными данными. Пример структуры:

```
    <Folder>
        <name>Company</name>
        <Placemark>
        <name>Company name</name>
        <description>Some description</description>
        <styleUrl>#icon-503-DB4436</styleUrl>
        <ExtendedData>
            <Data name='opis'>
                <value>Som desc.</value>
            </Data>
            <Data name='Informacje:'>
                <value>Some information </value>
            </Data>
            <Data name='Telefon:'>
                <value>(22) 333 55 55 (22)</value>
            </Data>
            <Data name='E-mail'>
                <value>qwerty@mail.com</value>
            </Data>
            <Data name='Strona:'>
                <value>www.google.com</value>
            </Data>
            <Data name='gx_media_links'>
                <value>some links</value>
            </Data>
        </ExtendedData>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>22.912227,52.12221,0.0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
</Folder>
```

Причина неправильного заполнения в черезмерной насыщенности текста элементом ; , есть ли возможность, на основании текущего кода, реализовать правильную конвертацию? Или какие варианты реализации целесообразно использовать в данной ситуации.

**Обновление**

Приведу полную версию кода для уточнение правильности чтения CSV с помощью CSVHelpera (имею проблему с выводом в XML, выводится только одна линия из CSV файла):

```
                    using (var sr = new StreamReader(Fd2.FileName))
            {
                var reader = new CsvReader(sr);


                IEnumerable<DataRecord> records = reader.GetRecords<DataRecord>();


                foreach (DataRecord record in records) // (int element in fibarray) (var record in DataRecord)
                {
                    XElement category = new XElement("Folder", new XElement("name", "NASI PARTNERZY HANDLOWI"), new XElement("Placemark", new XElement("name", record.name), new XElement("description", record.opis + "<br><br>Informacje: " + record.information + "<br>Telefon: " + record.telefon + "<br>E-mail: " + record.mail + "<br>Strona: " + record.strona + "<br>" + record.img), new XElement("styleUrl", record.icon), new XElement("ExtendedData",  new XElement("Data", new XAttribute("name", "gx_media_links"), new XElement("value", record.gx))), new XElement("Point", new XElement("coordinates", record.cordinates))));


                    using (var sw2 = new StreamWriter(xmlFile, false, Encoding.UTF8))
                        sw2.WriteLine(category);

                }
            }
```

Comment: Т.е. у Вас в тексте встречается никак не экранированный разделитель?

Comment: Да, к примеру с номерами телефонв: (22) 333 55 55 ; (22) 333 55 77, они в одной ячейке, но между ними разделитель ;

Comment: Соблюдается ли "Значения, содержащие зарезервированные символы (двойная кавычка, запятая, точка с запятой, новая строка) обрамляются двойными кавычками ("); если в значении встречаются кавычки — они представляются в файле в виде двух кавычек подряд."   ?

Comment: Пример линии с csv файла: "MEBLE"; "opis: Studio mebli kuchennych"; "#icon-503-DB4436"; "Studio mebli kuchennych"; ""; "(52) 560 2200 ; (52) 582 3300";"meble@gmail.com";"www.studiomega.net";"";"18.069182,53.12741900000001,0.0"

Comment: Также пробовал использовать "from str in source let fields = str.Split('"; "')" вместо "from str in source let fields = str.Split(';')" - это решило бы проблему, но тут заругался visual studio.

Comment: @IgKos: Последняя проблема в конструкторе `StreamWriter`: вы указали вторым параметром `false`, то есть запретили ему дописывать к старому файлу. Вот он каждый раз и затирает предыдущую строку новой.

Comment: @IgKos: Вообще, открывать/закрывать файл на каждую строку затратно. Делайте лучше так: http://pastebin.com/Y4798eXp

Comment: @VladD: Спасибо за подсказку. Но теперь столкнулся с такими проблемами: теперь каждый  блок включает в себя элемент <Folder> и <name>NASI PARTNERZY HANDLOWI</name> , вместо того, чтобы отобразить только вначале и </Folder> в конце, а далее поочередно выводить <Placemark> </Placemark>. И вторая проблема: в элементе description имею теги <br>, но на выходе получаю &lt;br&gt; и не до конца понимаю как это решить с помощью HtmlDecode Method.

Comment: @IgKos: Ну так вы ж на каждом шаге это добавляете сами! Добавьте вручную только то, что надо.

Comment: @IgKos: По поводу второй проблемы — так и надо же! Вы не можете представить в XML-тексте `<` иначе как через `&lt;`, иначе это будет частью XML-разметки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если значения полей не будут начинаться с ";" - то можно так:

```
let fields = str.Split(new[] { "\";" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
  .Select(x => x.Trim().Substring(1))
```

Comment: Работает, спасибо.

Answer (score 6):

Пожалуйста, прекратите обрабатывать CSV файлы "руками"!

CSV [не так прост](http://www.secretgeek.net/csv_trouble) как кажется. Из самых частых проблем:

- наличие сепаратора внутри значений ячеек ("some;data")
- наличие переноса строк внутри значений ячеек (причем переносы разных форматов -- Windows, Unix, Mac)
- наличие двойных кавычек внутри экранированных значений ячеек ("some""data")

Поэтому этом даже при наличии правильно сформированного файла тривиальное решение -- разбить его на строки, а каждую строку разбить `string.Split()'ом` -- не является корректным.

Используйте готовую библиотеку, авторы которой позаботились о закавыках формата. Например, [CsvHelper](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/). Как крайний вариант (если вдруг не устроит производительность готовых библиотек или у вас какой-то кастомный CSV), можно написать свой парсер, который обработает самые распространенные проблемы ([пример черновика парсера с использованием конечного автомата](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839096/parsing-csv-data-using-a-finite-state-machine)).

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы, и обработка "руками" - это результат недостаточного опыта и потребности в быстрых результатах. В ближайшие дни ознакомлюсь с технологией. Возможно, если у Вас, под руками, есть годные примеры, попрошу поделиться.

Comment: @IgKos в документации к CsvHelper'у все есть. Вам нужен класс `CsvParser` и метод `ReadLine()`.

Comment: Всё же попрошу помочь кодом, так как без особого опыта и множества живых примеров в интернете реализовать функционал не удалось.