# Чтение .csv файла с помощью StreamReader и построение графика

Tags: c#

Нужно считать с помощью *StreamReader* файл `.csv`. В файле очень много строк. В каждой строке по пять значений, которые разделяются запятыми. 
Я использую для этого

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Cursor Files|*.csv";
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Выберите ранее записанный график в формате .csv";

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            System.IO.StreamReader sr = new
            System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            data1_read =sr.ReadLine();

            string[] slist = data1_read.Split(',');       


            sr.Close();

            data_temp_in.Add(slist[0]);
            foreach (var temp_in in data_temp_in)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(temp_in) + "");
            }

        }
```

Но, как понимаю, я считываю всего лишь первую строку, так как больше никаких значений в *MessageBox*-е не появляется. (появляется только нулевое значение, которое считали из файла).

Как мне из файла с множеством строк считать столбцы, занести их в Коллекцию  и потом из этой коллекции построить уже график?

Раньше было проще - имеем два массива. Один — это значения Х, вторые значения Y, и всё, на основе этих данных строим график, а тут вообще не понятно.

Comment: График вы какой библиотекой строите? Как выглядит код для графика, когда вы работаете с массивами A и B?

Answer (score 2):

Файл прочитать и вывести в `MessageBox` можно так:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var fileName = GetFileNameFromDialog();

    if (fileName != null)
    {
        var list = ReadLines(fileName);

        foreach (var cells in list)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Join(" ", cells));
        }
    }
}

private DialogResult GetFileNameFromDialog()
{
    var dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    dialog.Filter = "Cursor Files|*.csv";
    dialog.Title = "Выберите ранее записанный график в формате .csv";
    return dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK ? dialog.FileName : null;    
}

private List<string[]> ReadLines(string fileName)
{
    var list = new List<string[]>();
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines();
    foreach(var line in lines)
    {
        var cells = line.Split(',');
        list.Add(cells);
    }
    return list;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Записывать в список `list` можно не только массивом строк. Описываем класс и меняем метод чтения из файла:

```
public class DataRow
{
    public string In;
    public string Out;
    public string Irrigation;
    public string TempTrigger;
    public string VpsRisk;
}

private List<DataRow> ReadLines(string fileName)
{
    var list = new List<DataRow>();
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines();
    foreach(var line in lines)
    {
        var cells = line.Split(',');
        var item = new DataRow();
        item.In = cells[0];
        item.Out = cells[1];
        item.Irrigation = cells[2];
        item.TempTrigger = cells[3];
        item.VpsRisk = cells[4];
        list.Add(cells);
    }
    return list;
}

//...
MessageBox.Show(cells.In + " " + cells.Out + " " + cells.Irrigation); // итд
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно ваш случай — вы читаете лишь одну строчку, а вам нужно прочитать их все и обработать в цикле. Например, так:

```
IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadLines(openFileDialog1.FileName);
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    string[] slist = line.Split(',');
    ...
```

Кроме того, формат csv не так прост, и лучше бы вам парсить его [не руками, а парсером](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/445574/10105).